# Approximating the distribution of the product of iid beta variates

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution, approximation

### Background

I am interested in the distribution of

$$\theta_0=1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\theta_i)$$

where the $\theta_{i>0}$ are iid beta random variates:

$$\theta_{i>0}\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$$

In my case $\beta\gg1\gg\alpha$ and $n\gg1$, so I used the following transformation:

$$\phi_i=-\ln(1-\theta_i)\\\theta_i=1-e^{-\phi_i}\\d\theta_i=e^{-\phi_i}\\p(\phi_i)\propto(1-e^{-\phi_{i}})^{\alpha-1}e^{-\phi_{i}\beta}\qquad\text{(1)}$$

With $\beta\gg\alpha$, $\theta_i$ and $\phi_i$ tend to be very small, so

$$1-e^{-\phi_i}\approx\phi_i$$

Substituting into (1) gives:

$$p(\phi_i)\hspace{1mm}\dot\propto\hspace{1mm}\phi_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\phi_i\beta}$$

Or

$$\phi_i\hspace{1mm}\dot\sim\hspace{1mm}\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$$

Define $\phi_0$:

$$\phi_0\equiv\sum_{i=1}^n\phi_i$$

Using the properties of the gamma distribution:

$$\phi_0\hspace{1mm}\dot\sim\hspace{1mm}\text{Gamma}(n\alpha,\beta)$$

Finally,

$$\theta_0=1-e^{-\phi_0}$$

(I can further improve the approximation through moment matching to get *slightly* different values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to use in the gamma distribution, but this doesn't affect the question below.)

### Question

What would be a good way to quantifiably demonstrate how well the above approximation works for varying values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $n$?

For a single set of values, I can use simulation, e.g.,

```
set.seed(214462480)
alpha <- 2e-3
beta <- 1001
n <- 1e3
theta0.sim1 <- -expm1(replicate(1e5, sum(log1p(-rbeta(n, alpha, beta)))))
theta0.sim2 <- -expm1(-rgamma(1e5, n*alpha, beta))
ks.test(theta0.sim1, theta0.sim2)$p.value
#> [1] 0.5396774
```

And the `ecdf` lines are right on top of each other.

However, simulation in this manner is slow and defeats the purpose of the approximation. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are sampled from a joint posterior, so I require a large number of samples of $\theta_0$, each with varying $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters. Furthermore, this will be applied to a number of problems, so $n$ and the distributions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can also vary.

Comment: If you want to use a gamma distribution as an approximation, then note that $1-\theta_i\sim \text{Beta}(\beta, \alpha)$ and you can then use the method of moments to match the first two moments of a gamma distribution.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I do in the end, with $-\ln{(1-\theta_i)}$ being approximated as a gamma distribution. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ end up being really good initial estimates for the gamma parameters (so good that a *single* Newton-Raphson iteration does best for getting the final values using double precision).

Comment: Simulation is slow because your sample sizes are huge.  You can test the quality of the approximation with a relatively small number of replicates: often, even 50 will work fine.  Shortening the simulation makes it possible to create and inspect a large number of probability plots of your distributions so you can learn just how close they tend to be and how much they vary, as well as permitting you to explore a wide range of combinations of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me your thoughts. So far I'm getting that the best way to go about it is to manually characterize the 3-D $(\alpha,\beta,n)$ space by visually inspecting a large number of plots. If that's the case, I agree that P-P plots are probably the way to go. I was trying to come up with something that could be more easily automated and communicated to the users of the model. I'll keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extended comment.  One can obtain the exact distribution (and mean and variance) of $\phi_{i>0}$ although for the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you mention, the result differs little from your approximation.  (It can make a big difference for other values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.)

Again, using *Mathematica*:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[-Log[θ], θ \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[β, α]];

PDF[dist, ϕ]
```

[image: PDF of phi]

```
μϕ = Mean[dist]
(* -PolyGamma[0, β] + PolyGamma[0, α + β] *)

σ2ϕ = Variance[dist]
(* PolyGamma[1, β] - PolyGamma[1, α + β] *)

sol = Solve[{μϕ == a b, σ2ϕ == a b^2}, {a, b}][[1]]
```

[image: Solutions for gamma approximation]

For your values of $\alpha=2/1000$ and $\beta=1001$ the values of $a$ and $b$ are

```
sol /. {β -> 1001, α -> 2/1000} // N
{a -> 0.002, b -> 0.000999499}
```

Comment: I instead equated the moments of $e^{-\dot\phi_0}$ with those of $1-\theta_0$, where $\dot\phi_0\sim\text{gamma}(a,b)$ in order to find $a$ and $b$. That way the approximating distribution matches the first two moments of the true distribution of the variable of interest ($\theta_0$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "visual" approach (using *Mathematica*) to check on the gamma approximation for the distribution of $\theta_0$.

```
nsamples = 10000; (* Number of random samples *)
Manipulate[
 (* Random sample of θ0 values *)
 x = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[β, α], {nsamples, n}];
 θ0 = 1 - Times @@ # & /@ x;
 
 (* Find gamma distribution parameters with same mean and variance *)
 (* θ0Var = E(θi^2)^n - E(θi)^(2n) *);
 θ0Var = (Variance[BetaDistribution[β, α]] + Mean[BetaDistribution[β, α]]^2 // Together)^n -
   Mean[BetaDistribution[β, α]]^(2 n);
 θ0Mean = 1 - Mean[BetaDistribution[β, α]]^n;
 {a, b} = {a0, b0} /. Solve[{θ0Mean == a0 b0, θ0Var == a0 b0^2}, {a0, b0}][[1]] // Quiet;
 
 (* Display histogram and approximating gamma density *)
 Show[Histogram[θ0, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, Automatic},
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)",  "Density"}],
  Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]],
 {{n, 1001, Style["n", Italic, 14]}, 10, 2000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{α, 1/1000, Style["α", 14]}, 1/1000, 1/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{β, 1001, Style["β", 14]}, 50, 5000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: Histogram and approximating density for various values of n, alpha, and beta]

Something similar could be done with a cdf.

The values of $a$ and $b$ for the approximating gamma distribution are

$$a=\frac{\left(\left(\frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta }\right)^n-1\right)^2}{\left(\frac{\beta ^2+\beta }{(\alpha +\beta ) (\alpha +\beta +1)}\right)^n-\left(\frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta }\right)^{2 n}}$$

$$b=\frac{\left(\frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta }\right)^{2 n}-\left(\frac{\beta ^2+\beta }{(\alpha +\beta ) (\alpha +\beta +1)}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta }\right)^n-1}$$

The above code can be modified to produce a P-P plot (as suggested by @whuber):

```
nsamples = 10000; (* Number of random samples *)
Manipulate[
 (* Random sample of θ0 values *)
 x = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[β, α], {nsamples, n}];
 θ0 = 1 - Times @@ # & /@ x // Sort;
 
 (* Find gamma distribution parameters with same mean and variance *)
 (* θ0Var = E(θi^2)^n - E(θi)^(2n) *);
 θ0Var = (Variance[BetaDistribution[β, α]] + Mean[BetaDistribution[β, α]]^2 // Together)^n -
   Mean[BetaDistribution[β, α]]^(2 n);
 θ0Mean = 1 - Mean[BetaDistribution[β, α]]^n;
 {a, b} = {a0, b0} /. Solve[{θ0Mean == a0 b0, θ0Var == a0 b0^2}, {a0, b0}][[1]] // Quiet;
 
 (* Display histogram and approximating gamma density *)
 t = Table[{i/nsamples, CDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], θ0[[i]]], 
    CDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], θ0[[i]]] - (i - 1/2)/nsamples},
   {i, nsamples}];
 GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, t[[All, {1, 2}]]}, 
    Joined -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1,
    PlotLabel -> Style["P-P Plot", Bold, 18], 
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"p", "CDF(Gamma(a,b))"}],
   ListPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, t[[All, {1, 3}]]}, 
    Joined -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic},
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"p", "CDF(Gamma(a,b)) - p"}]}],

 {{n, 1001, Style["n", Italic, 14]}, 10, 2000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{α, 2/1000, Style["α", 14]}, 1/1000, 1/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{β, 1001, Style["β", 14]}, 50, 5000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n, α, β}]
```

[image: P-P and difference plot]

The plot on the right highlights the size of the departures for a particular random sample.

Comment: For this kind of study you will get much more out of P-P plots than by overplotting histograms, especially if you're interested in accuracy out in the tails.

Comment: @whuber Agreed.  I do think the use of the sliders helps one to check out a variety of combinations relatively quickly such that any combinations of parameters that result in gross departures can be spotted.

Comment: Thank you for the Mathematica script. I do like the sliders. If I were to take a manual approach, I would definitely want to (semi-) automate the plotting this way. However, note that I'm using $-\ln{(1-\theta_{i>0})}\dot\sim\text{Gamma}(a,b)$ rather than $\theta_0\dot\sim\text{Gamma}(a,b)$, although the latter seems to be working pretty well with the example values I gave.

Comment: +1 -- really nice solution.